# React-webcam on EC2 Instance

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2, webcam, mern, react-fullstack

i am currently working on a MERN project which uses react webcam and have deployed it over an EC2 instance. The react-webcam works just fine on localhost but it doesnt throw an error or display the video when i run the project on the instance. Im very new to deployment on EC2 instances. Why does it not work and what is the solution to this?

the webcam component is the basic react-webcam code found on npm
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-webcam

Comment: There's absolutely no error? Are there any other differences in behavior between localhost and the EC2 environment? Are you using HTTPS or HTTP to access the app?

Comment: it doesnt display anything. just a blank screen. no errors/warnings related to react-webcam on the console either. i am using HTTP. All my other pages render just fine EXCEPT for the react-webcam component.

Comment: Could be the protocol. At the top of the docs for react-webcam: "Note: Browsers will throw an error if the page is loaded from insecure origin. I.e. Use https."